# Rails4: Can't modify frozen hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

The `Order` model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order
end
```

has_many `Sale`s:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :sales
  validates :order, :product, :product_group, :presence => true
  before_create :price

  def price
    mrr = Warehouse.where(:product => self.product).pluck(:mrr).shift.strip.sub(',', '.').to_f
    self.price = mrr * self.quantity.to_f
  end
end
```

When I destroy an `Order`, the associated `Sale`s should also be destroyed, but I ran into an error when doing so:

```
RuntimeError in OrdersController#destroy
Can't modify frozen hash
```

This line is highlighted: `self.price = mrr * self.quantity.to_f`.

Destroying all associated `Sale`s records manually step-by-step works without errors. After no `Sale` is associated anymore, I can destroy the `Order` record too.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On the line that gets highlighted you should make sure that `sale` is not destroyed when updating its `price` attribute:

```
self.price = mrr * quantity.to_f unless destroyed? # notice, no need for self before quantity
# or
write_attribute(:price, mrr * quantity.to_f) unless destroyed?
```

Comment: Great! I was looking for it to fix a deep bug in the EavHashes gem.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and searched for an answer.  Only found the discussion about destroyed;  However I've determined that if I create a new active record (find_or_create_by) and then create a second object dependent on the first active record, i get the same error.  I resolved it by saving the first active Record before creating/modifying the second.  I don't understand why the create is necessary, although I can see why the second record wants the first to exist before it gets saved/modified.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded Rails from **4.1** to **4.2.5** and got this error when tried save object with tags.

In my case trouble was due **gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'** which should be upgraded to newer version >= 3.4.